# On button click I want to set the value of text field to zero using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I want delete button to set the text field value to zero

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ptcR.png)

HTML CODE

```
 <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>French Fries</td>
        <td>&#8377; 110</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="5" step="1" name="item1"/>
          <button onclick="buttonClick(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">ADD</button>
          <button id="qty" onclick="deleteClick(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-1" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Garlic Bread</td>
        <td>&#8377; 99</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" value="0" min="0" max="5" step="1" name="item2"/>
          <button onclick="buttonClick(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">ADD</button>
          <button id = "qty" onclick="deleteClick(this)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-1" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

JavaScript

```
function deleteClick(element) {
  let qtyBox = document.getElementById("qty");
   qtyBox.Value = parseInt("0");
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to go with getElementById, kindly include 'id' attribute to both of your  elements such as 'qty1', 'qty2' and pass it to your on clear function!

```js
function deleteClick(element) {
   if(element.id === "qty1") {
    document.getElementById("qty1").value = parseInt("0");
   }
   if(element.id === "qty2") {
    document.getElementById("qty2").value = parseInt("0");
   }
   
  }
```

```html
 <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>French Fries</td>
        <td>&#8377; 110</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="qty1" value="0" min="0" max="5" step="1" name="item1"/>
          <button onclick="buttonClick(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">ADD</button>
          <button id="qty" onclick="deleteClick(qty1)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-1" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">Clear</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Garlic Bread</td>
        <td>&#8377; 99</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" id="qty2" value="0" min="0" max="5" step="1" name="item2"/>
          <button onclick="buttonClick(this)" type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">ADD</button>
          <button id = "qty" onclick="deleteClick(qty2)" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-1" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete">Clear</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you  pass the name of the input to the function on the button click then you can directly target that and alter the value.

Note that I removed the add buttons for simplicity to demonstrate the delete functionality.

```js
function deleteClick(name) {
  document.getElementsByName(name)[0].value = 0;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
        <th scope="row">1</th>
        <td>French Fries</td>
        <td>&#8377; 110</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" value="3" min="0" max="5" step="1" name="item1"/>
          <button id="qty1" onclick="deleteClick('item1')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-1" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th scope="row">2</th>
        <td>Garlic Bread</td>
        <td>&#8377; 99</td>
        <td>
          <input type="number" value="2" min="0" max="5" step="1" value="2" name="item2"/>
          <button id = "qty2" onclick="deleteClick('item2')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm rounded-1" type="button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Delete</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
</table>
```